# The usage of "now" in an update

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

My colleague and I write articles about a social media's updates on the platform (e.g. Twitter dark mode, Facebook ad placements).

Whenever we write our articles, we indicate the date to inform the reader when the update rolled out. Should we still add the word "now" even if the date was already added?

For example,

"Facebook announced an update on ads placement on June 8, 2019. Now, businesses can decide where to place their ads on a video or on users' Facebook feeds."

The reason I try not to use "now" in articles because let's say someone's reading this article a week or month later, would the word now still be applicable by that time?

I'd really like your take on this. Thanks!

Comment: I think most readers will be intelligent enough to know that 'now' was correct at the time of writing, even if they are reading the article months later.

Comment: An update is assumed to persist unless re-updated, so "now" is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of the sentence is quite clear with the usage of "Now". However, you can also use "From now on" which is a little more elaborate.

Some of the more literary alternatives would be "henceforth" or "hereafter".

Alteration of the sentence as 
"Facebook announced an update on ads placement on June 8, 2019 which lets businesses decide where to place their ads on a video or on users' Facebook feeds." may also work.